# Parse an XML dynamically

Tags: xml, oracle, xml-parsing

I am trying to create a procedure which reads an XML from a table and parse the values and insert the values into another table

```
 CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE Xml_parser 
    AS 
      TYPE cur_type IS ref CURSOR; 
      vxml         XMLTYPE; 
      vvalue       VARCHAR2(100); 
      l_cur_string VARCHAR2(150); 
      vxpath       contractresignxml_master.xpath%TYPE; 
      vnodename    contractresignxml_master.nodename%TYPE; 
      select_cur   CUR_TYPE; 
      verror       VARCHAR2(500); 
      CURSOR cur_xml_master IS 
        SELECT xpath, 
               nodename 
        FROM   xml_master; 
    BEGIN 
        SELECT xml_col 
        INTO   vxml 
        FROM   holds_xml; 

        OPEN cur_xml_master; 

        LOOP 
            FETCH cur_xml_master INTO vxpath, vnodename; 

            EXIT WHEN cur_xml_master%NOTFOUND; 

            L_Cur_String := 'Select e.'
                            ||Vnodename||
                            ' From Xmltable(''/changeRequest/customerOrganisation'' Passing Xmltype('
                            ||Vxml||
                            ') columns '
                            ||Vnodename||
                            ' path '
                            ||Vxpath||
                            ' )e';

    OPEN select_cur FOR l_cur_string; 

    LOOP 
        FETCH select_cur INTO vvalue; 

        EXIT WHEN select_cur%NOTFOUND; 


        dbms_output.Put_line (vnodename 
                              ||' ' 
                              ||vxpath 
                              ||':' 
                              ||vvalue); 
    END LOOP; 

    CLOSE select_cur; 
    END LOOP; 

    CLOSE cur_xml_master; 
    END;
```

xpath is the path of the xml and nodename just refers to the name of the xml tag. There are hundreds of xpath for which I want to get the value in some variable and insert in other tables
vxml is the xml which I want to parse.

I am trying to generate a select statement dynamically which parses the xml for each xpath but getting an error as "Error(27,25): PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to '||'"

Is there some other way to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because you're trying to concatenate the XMLType variable, but the [concatenation operator](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/operators003.htm) only allows strings (CHAR, VARCHAR2 or CLOB). While you *could* extract the CLOB value and include that, enclosed in quotes, it isn't a great idea.

Instead you can pass the XMLType PL/SQL variable as a bind variable. Since it is already that type, you don't the the `XMLType()` call in the `passing` clause. The `path` being supplied also needs to be quoted, if the value in your master table column does not include quotes already. So change your dynamic statement to:

```
        L_Cur_String := 'Select e."'
                        ||Vnodename||
                        '" From Xmltable(''/changeRequest/customerOrganisation'' '
                        || 'Passing :xml columns "'
                        ||Vnodename||
                        '" varchar2(200) path '''
                        ||Vxpath||
                        ''' )e';
```

And then pass the `vxml` variable to use as the `:xml` bind placeholder:

```
OPEN select_cur FOR l_cur_string USING vxml;
```

Comment: The procedure got compiled. But while running it I get an error as "ORA-00902: invalid datatype". The statement which is generated is Select E.Y-Coordinate 
From Xmltable('/changeRequest/customerOrganisation' 
Passing :xml columns y-coordinate path 'changeRequest/billOfMaterials/bomSiteItem/coordinates/y-coordinate' )e

Comment: @Vishal5364 - the name you have, `y-coordinate`, isn't a valid identifier, so part of it is being interpreted as an identifier and part as a data type. I've modified the dynamic query to enclose the `vnodename` in double quotes in both places it's used. Also note that the value of that, from your table, can't exceed 30 characters. (Ideally you should specify the data type too, otherwise the default you get might not be appropriate and could cause problems later when you insert or use the generated value. The documentation shows it as required; you seem to get a string without it though)

Comment: Thanks, I had figured that it can be a problem with y-coordinate. I still have some issues after correcting it. Select e."y-coordinate" From Xmltable('/changeRequest/customerOrganisation' Passing :xml columns "y-coordinate" path 'changeRequest/billOfMaterials/bomSiteItem/coordinates/y-coordinate' )e it throws error "ORA-19224: XPTY0004 - XQuery static type mismatch: expected - node()* got - xs:string "

Comment: @Vishal5364 - maybe your version is defaulting differently; with some made-up data this works fine for me in 11.2.0.4. Maybe you can add the actual XML you're parsing and your DB version to the question? From the error your version seems to be expecting an XML node not a string. I've added a datatype to the code, which you might want to tweak depending on your expected data; ideally your master table would supply the expected actual data type for each node too, I suppose.

Comment: I know I am bothering you too much, but while running the procedure after changes, it doesn't get inside second loop . How do I get the procedure to run completely and get the value of xml into some variable. I am totally stuck

Comment: If it isn't going into the second loop (how are you checking?) then the path doesn't exist in the XML. Have you `set serveroutput on` before running it? As I said before, it would really help if you put the actual XML into the question. It seems slightly odd to have two nodes both called 'changeRequest'.

Comment: The XML is really big so I am unable to add it here. Also the path exists in the XML still it's not getting inside the loop.

Comment: How do you know it isn't getting inside the loop? How are you executing the procedure? Which client are you using? Have you enabled output (e.g. `set serveroutput on`)?

Comment: Yes I have enabled output and have written print statements inside it to see the flow e.g.  OPEN select_cur FOR cur_string USING vxml; 
          dbms_output.Put_line ('after open');

                LOOP 
                    FETCH select_cur INTO vvalue; 
                
                    EXIT WHEN select_cur%NOTFOUND;
                    dbms_output.Put_line ('after exit');   I am getting "after open" as output but not "after exit" . I am using 11.2.0.4.0

Comment: Then your path does not match. Are you really sure you have `/changeRequest/customerOrganisation/changeRequest/billOfMaterials/bomSiteItem/coordinates/y-coordinate`? Without seeing your actual XML, are you sure the XPath in the first clause shouldn't just be the top level node, i.e. `from Xmltable('/' Passing ...` ?

Comment: The path matches. I have changes the path to top level node and it works for some of the iterations. For 1 iteration I get the error as "ORA-19279: XPTY0004 - XQuery dynamic type mismatch: expected singleton sequence - got multi-item sequence". The select query is Select e."y-coordinate" From Xmltable('/' Passing :xml columns "y-coordinate" varchar2(200) path 'changeRequest/billOfMaterials/bomSiteItem/coordinates/y-coordinate' )e.. I can give you the XML by mail if its fine with you.

Comment: You could stick it in [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) or similar, but not if it holds any data you're not supposed to share - if it's real customer data, then not a good idea. The error suggests you have at least one request with two y-coordinate values, I think. But, this is nothing to do with your original question...

Comment: It doesn't have real data, but I cant access pastebin or any similar site from my office.